# Plot Sum of column by values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the sample data below.  I would like to create a plot showing the sum of the "Correct" column by each of the other 4 columns, when those columns have value 1.  The columns are dummy variables, so a 1 in the "Chinese" column indicates that record was flagged as Chinese.  So I'd like to create a bar plot showing sum of "Correct" for each dummy variable.

Sample Data:

```
           Food  Chinese  Italian  Food Stands    \
176          1     0        0        0                     
148          0     0        0        0                    
143          0     1        0        0                      
45           0     1        0        0                    

     Correct  
176        0  
148        1  
143        0  
45         1
```

Comment: So just sum columns where `Correct` has a `1` value?

Comment: @Jarad Actually the other way around, just sum "Correct" when the other fields have a 1 in them.  So in this example it would be a plot where "Chinese" would have 1 and the other fields would be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.dot`

```
df.drop('Correct', 1).T.dot(df.Correct).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, it uses **mask** to only create column sums from rows where *Correct*=1

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Chinese'] = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
df['Italian'] = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
df['Correct'] = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0]

df.mask(df['Correct'].apply(lambda x: bool(x)), inplace=True)
df[['Italian','Chinese']].sum().plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I don't think I made myself clear in the original post.  I want to sum the "Correct" column, but only when the value in Chinese is 1.  I also gave poor sample data.  So with this sample data the plot would just show Chinese with 1.  The other fields would have 0.